# Pig converting a time stamp passed to a pig script and using the replace function

Tags: apache-pig

```
REPLACE(ToDate('$current__ts', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'),'-','') as new_DT,
```

I am trying to convert the current_ts or timestamp passed with removal of - between YYYY-mm-dd so the output should be yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss

but i get the error:
**Could not infer the matching function for org.apache.pig.builtin.REPLACE as multiple or none of them fit. Please use an explicit cast.**

I also tried the below same error

```
REPLACE((datetime)ToDate('$current__ts', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'),'-','') as new_DT,
```

Comment: please add few lines of input data ! try
 REPLACE(ToDate($current__ts, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'),'-','')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ToDate](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/func.html#to-date) returns a datetime object.[REPLACE](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/func.html#replace) works on a string. You have to cast the datetime object from the ToDate to a chararray and then use it in the REPLACE function.See [ToString](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/func.html#to-string)

```
REPLACE(ToString(ToDate('$current__ts', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')),'-','') as new_DT,
```